# Using @ character on http auth for git pull

Tags: git, http-authentication

I need to run this command:

`git pull "https://user:password@bitbucket.com/user/repo.git" master`

My problem, the password include the @ character, and I end with an error like: "host asd@bitbucket.com couldn't found" where "asd" is the last part of the password.

How can I get around this?

**Note:** I know the security issues about this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to encode @-symbol like this `%40` ([Percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding))